how to handle the where clause for encrypted data in postgresql?
I am working with a PostgreSQL database and need to encrypt sensitive data fields (like SSN and email) for security purposes. However, I want to be able to query these encrypted fields efficiently, especially using WHERE clauses, without decrypting each row individually during the query.
I am using pgcrypto to encrypt sensitive data, and I've set up a trigger to automatically encrypt the data before inserting it into the database.
The problem arises when I try to query encrypted fields using a WHERE clause. Since the data is encrypted, PostgreSQL cannot directly filter on these fields without decrypting every row, which is inefficient. I'm looking for a way to make WHERE queries feasible on encrypted data.
Is there a recommended approach for handling WHERE clauses on encrypted data in PostgreSQL? I am open to using other methods or functions if they make querying more efficient.
I understand that using a function to decrypt data as needed might result in overhead, as pointed out. I'm trying to avoid performance bottlenecks. I'd appreciate any guidance on minimizing this overhead or achieving an efficient way to query encrypted data.

pgcrypto is for cryptographic functions - I get the feeling that it is not intended for encrypting+decrypting columns on the fly like this (not least because it will absolutely wreck performance due to having to use non-SARGable queries). It sounds like you want PostgresTDE (Transparent Data Encryption), which is an EnterpriseDB feature.

i'll take a look at tde , thank you.

it encrypts the disks, but in the WAL, backups, still the data won't be encrypted, it's not what i want

The short answer: if you store encrypted data in the database, you cannot use an index to search for them efficiently. Security limits performance and ease of use, and in this case, the performance hit is the price you have to pay for security.
The exception to the above is if you use a deterministic encryption method (which is not ideal for security) and search with =: then you can use an index to search for the encrypted data.
Note that using pgcrypto to encrypt your data is not very secure: you have to send the clear text and the encryption key to the database, so you cannot protect the data from the database administrator. It is better to encrypt the data inside the application.

i work as a dba, so u think this kind of encryption is the developper job not the dba?

Yes, I very much think that encrypting the data is not the DBA's job. The DBA is ose of the people you might want to protect the data from.

"encrypting the data is not the DBA's job" - someone's being controversial...

@Dai I'm not trying to be controversial, but a short comment can be incomplete. Encrypting inside the database (which is what this question is about) is the job of the application, not the DBA's job. Encrypring the database files, if desired (data-at-rest encryption) would be the DBA's job. And as always, this is my opinion.

but still , i wanna learn how to handle such things , beside the encryption will be on the fly so even i, as a dba won't be able to see the data

... unless you log the statements; then you see the private key.

Actually there are few ways that are still considered secure to search on an encrypted data in postgres:

Blind Indexing for Exact Match Searches:
To enable exact match searches (WHERE x = y) without decrypting every row, you can use a blind index. This involves hashing your sensitive data and storing the hash alongside the encrypted field as another column. When you need to search, you hash the input and compare it to the stored hashes.
Instead of complicating things with SQL functions, you can handle the hashing in your application code.
SELECT encrypted_ssn FROM your_table WHERE ssn_blind_index = '<hashed_ssn>';

This keeps your SQL straightforward. Make sure you are using a secure hashing algorithm and that you add a salt to the hashed data to keep things secure.

Use a Third-Party Solution:
If you need to perform substring or pattern matching (WHERE x LIKE y) on encrypted data, then there are significantly more complex index data structures and algorithm that can be used to index the data but it might be too complex to explain in a stack overflow answer.
Fortunately, there are existing solutions that implement just that. You could use a solution like Piiano Vault that provides built-in support for querying encrypted data, including exact match & substring searches using the techniques mentioned above and more protective measures to protect sensitive data.
Vault works with postgres internally so you can set it up as a self hosted service that runs in front of your postgres to handle sensitive data or use the cloud option to avoid managing it yourself.
Advantages:

Simplicity: Handles encryption, indexing, and querying so you don't have to build it from scratch.
Key Management: Automatically takes care of key rotation and secure key storage and can work with a key you provide.
Extra Security: Offers additional protective measures beyond just encrypting data.

Considerations:

External Dependency: Adds a third-party component to your stack.
Might Be Overkill: If you don't need all the extra features, it might be more than you need.
Price: Obviously there is additional cost to it in addition to your current database cost though you might argue if you really need these features then paying for them might be more cost effective than develop and maintain them on your own.

Full disclosure: I'm a software engineer at Piiano.


In my experience, if you just need exact match searches, blind indexing with hashing in your application code is a simple and effective solution but make sure you use a secure hashing algorithm and that you add a salt to every hash.
For more complex searching needs, especially if you want to save time and avoid complexity, a tool like Piiano Vault or similar alternatives can be a real lifesaver.
